Relationship between Gini impurity and misclassification error
I understand the differences between Gini Impurity and misclassification error, but I am curious if the following result that deals with the relationship between the two is true:
Assume we have two sets of probabilities $p_i$ and $q_i$, with $0 \leq p_i \leq 1$, $\forall i=1, 2, \ldots, m$ and $0 \leq q_i \leq 1$, $\forall i=1, 2, \ldots, n$. Furthermore, assume we have two sets of weights $w_i$ and $v_i$ that each sum to 1, i.e., $w_1+w_2+\cdots+w_m=1$ and $v_1+v_2+\cdots+v_n=1$. If
$\sum_{i=1}^m w_i 2p_i(1-p_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n v_i 2q_i(1-q_i)$,
does this imply
$\sum_{i=1}^m w_i (1-\max(p_i, 1-p_i)) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n v_i (1-\max(q_i, 1-q_i))$?
In other words, does a split that has a lower weighted Gini Impurity than another split also have a lower weighted misclassification error? It seems to be the case, due to the shape of the Gini impurity and misclassification error curves, but I cannot prove (or disprove) this rigorously.
